# Django 4.2.2 not respecting STORAGES['default']['BACKEND']

Tags: python, django, boto3

Using `settings.py`:

```py
STORAGES = {
    "staticfiles": {
        "BACKEND": "storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage",
    },
    "mediafiles": {
        "BACKEND": "storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage",
    },
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage",
    },
}
```

and running:

```py
    from django.conf import settings
    print('settings.DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE', settings.DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE)
```

prints:
`settings.DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage`

Media is writing to local and not S3 and this must be why. Static, for some reason, writes to S3 no problem. Any help or ideas would be appreciated.

The full codebase can be seen here: https://github.com/rkuykendall/Simplici7y

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the library `django-imagekit` had not been released since adding Django 4.2 support.